# How to update arduino wifi shield firmware?

Tags: arduino, xively

I am having trouble following the procedure on the Arduino website to update the wifi shield firmware. Here's the [link](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/WiFiShieldFirmwareUpgrading#.UyT9kvldW6w).

The outlined procedure is hard for me to follow, including what files to download from Github and where to store them on my computer.

I then am unsure of exactly what to enter in the command prompt.

Also, the error I was getting in the command prompt is when `Opening Port- Fail could not open USB device`
This would make me think that I need drivers or something, but nowhere I searched has said this.

I have done lots of searching and I can't find any good tutorials on how to upgrade the wifi shield firmware on a windows computer.
Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!
Heath

I finally figured out how to upgrade the firmware and I documented the process. However, I am unsure of how to post the process that I saved as a pdf and Word document.

Comment: Just FYI. There is now a stack dedicated to Arduino http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: I too have this problem.  Is there any visual tutorial to show how this works?

Comment: I figured out how to update the firmware but now I am unsure of how to share the word/pdf document that shows the process here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

1)Make sure that you're connected directly to the shield alone. Do not mount it on anything.

2)Make sure the right driver is installed for the shield. For windows, the driver comes with "Flip". You can find them inside the installed directory.